# Problema de conexão do PHP com o MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Todas as configurações estão certas não sei por não ta conectando.. localmente funciona, mas quando passo pro servidor dá esse problema.

```
$hostnome = '192.185.176.204';
$usernome = 'tookc892';
$senha = '***'
$conexao = mysql_connect('$hostnome', '$usernome' , '$senha');
```

Comment: Insira o trecho do código que apresenta o problema, para que possamos verificar.

Comment: Tem um texto muito estranho ali no meio... (?)

Comment: $hostnome = '192.185.176.204';
$usernome = 'tookc892';
$senha = '***'

$conexao= mysql_connect( '$hostnome', '$usernome' , '$senha');

// a senha não botei ai mais ta correta aqui

Comment: Você sabe que pode aceitar respostas? Veja em [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Você pode aceitar uma resposta por pergunta que fez. Pode até aceitar a sua resposta se foi a que melhor ajudou você.

Comment: Há dois possíveis motivos: 1º mysql_query está sendo descontinuado, 2º você pode estar entrando em um loop de conexão infinito.

Answer (score 5):

Você está usando aspas simples em sua conexão.

As variáveis dentro das aspas simples não são compiladas pelo PHP, portando, o servidor está tentando literalmente se conectar com o usuário `'$usuario'`, ao host `'$hostnome'` com a senha `'$senha'` e não com o valor contido nas variáveis, como você deseja.

Remova as aspas simples que deve de funcionar:

```
<?php $conexao= mysql_connect( $hostnome, $usernome , $senha);
```

*OBS: As funções mysql_* estão sendo descontinuadas pelo PHP, portanto, prefira trabalhar com algo mais novo e seguro, como o mysqli ou PDO.*

Comment: Fiz as alterações mas continua com o mesmo erro :/

Comment: @PatiiHenrii Parece estar havendo também um bloqueio pelo MySQL, talvez devido a muitos acessos com dados inválidos.

Comment: Correção de concordancia, o PHP compila sim o conteudo de aspas simples, ele só não interpreta variáveis dentro das mesmas... Até por que o uso de aspas simples é mais leve do que de aspas duplas, ou seja, em casos onde não existem variáveis dentro da string o melhor é utilizar aspas simples para ter um processamento otimizado.

Comment: @RodrigoBorth pois é, não me expressei muito bem em primeiro momento, obrigado pela correção. ^^

Comment: +1 por reforçar o uso de outras tecnologias no lugar da deprecada ```mysql_*```, além da resposta claro.

Answer (score 4):

Seu hostname foi bloqueado pelo MySQL por exceder o padrão de 10 tentativas...
Abra o console do seu MySQL e entre com:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=10000;
```

Referência: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blocked-host.html

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro erro foi explicado pelo Mateus, não deveria existir aspas simples no seu mysql_connect. 
Depois de muitas tentativas de conexão com erro seu host foi bloqueado, você tem que desbloquear ele com o comando: mysqladmin flush-hosts para poder acessar novamente.

Funciona localmente porque a configuração do mysql local deve ser diferente da configuração remota.

Aproveito para reforçar também que você deve abandonar os comandos mysql* substituíndo pelo menos por mysqli* sob risco de um dia seu site parar de funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

```
$hostnome = '192.185.176.204';
$usernome = 'tookc892';
$senha = '***';
$dbname = 'nome_banco';
$conexao = mysql_connect("$hostnome", "$usernome", "$senha");
$sel_banco = mysql_select_db("$dbname");
```

Esqueceu do ponto e vírgula depois da variável $senha;
Ainda falta selecionar o banco de dados...
Você deve executar $conexao, então poderia deixar sem defini-la, assim:

```
$hostnome = '192.185.176.204';
$usernome = 'tookc892';
$senha = '***';
$dbname = 'nome_banco';
mysql_connect("$hostnome, $usernome, $senha");
mysql_select_db("$dbname");
```

### EM PDO:

```
<?php
//Arquivo de conexão com o Banco de Dados
try{
    $driver = 'mysql';
    $host = '192.185.176.204';
    $usuario = 'tookc892';
    $senha = '***';
    $dbname = 'nome_banco';

    $conn = new PDO("$driver:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $usuario, $senha); 
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "Erro ao conectar no banco de dados $dbname <BR/>";
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

?>
```

Comment: Eu já fiz toda essas configurações e ainda ta dando o mesmo erro.. por muitas tentativas de conexão. me ajuda.. :(

Comment: Você conseguiu solucionar seu problema?

Comment: Andei olhando o manual do MySQL, você pode abrir seu phpmyadmin, ir na guia SQL e executar o seguinte comando: 

SHOW STATUS

As informações retornadas destaques são: Connections (conexões) e Aborted_connects (conexões abortadas). 
Veja se há muitas conexões abortadas, talvez isto possa ser o problema, então você necessitará resetar as conexões falhadas.

Pelo que andei observando você pode resetar com o comando: mysql_reset_connection()
Que funciona a partir do MySQL 5.7.3.

Veja mais sobre o comando em:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-reset-connection.html

Comment: O MySQL aborta conexões (MySQL Aborted_connects) quando:  
- Um cliente não tem privilégios para conectar a um banco de dados.  
- Um cliente usa uma senha incorreta.  
- Um pacote de conexão não contém as informações corretas.

Answer (score -1):

Um exemplo de conexão em POO, costumava usar ela acho que está funcionando ...

```
class Db{

//Variáveis Privadas//

private $user       = 'root';
private $password   = 'senha';
private $database   = 'nomedobanco';
private $host       = 'localhost'; 

/**************************************
*              Conectar              *
*      Função de conexão protected   *
**************************************/
 protected function conect(){
   if( mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password)){
       if(!mysql_select_db($this->database)){
            return ('Erro na seleção do banco');
       }else{
            return true;
       }
   }else{        
       return ('Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados.');
   }
 }
}
```

Espero que ajude ...

Comment: Bem, eu não recomendaria fazer isso pelos seguintes motivos: Sua classe esta gerando um acoplamento elevado, Não existem parâmetros, logo poderia ter itens estáticos. Caso eu necessite alterar alguma informação do meu DB eu precisaria alterar o código da minha classe. Você está usando funções que estão sendo descontinuadas então, logo a classe se tornara inútil e terá de ser reescrita. Estes são os principais porquês, mas existem vários outros.. =/

Comment: A ideia era algo didático, não sabia que no PHP5.5 ia decriptar as funções de mysql_, as variáveis privates eram só pra facilitar a visão, hoje em dia tem PDO, alias você também usou o mesmo que eu, parece meio confuso me negativar mas beleza.

Comment: Não fui eu que negativei. ;) hehe